# Checked radio button on select option change

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, select-options

When I change the value of a select option, a corresponding radio button should be clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorselector').on('change', function() {

        if ( this.value == 'red')
        {
            $('input[name="purchase[product_id]"][value="000000"][type="radio"]').click();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
.prop('checked',true);
```

instead of

```
.click();
```

if what you wanted is to make the radio "checked"